# LaTeX Macbook Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \usemintedstyle

Tags: macos, latex, tex, pdflatex

I am trying to create a report on TeXstudio (Mac) but for **\usemintedstyle{borland}** and **\begin{document}** commands I am getting errors:

*Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \usemintedstyle
Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}*

How can I fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your `commands` tab of the texstudio preferences, you are might just missing the shell-escape flag or  maybe you did not install pygmentize